# How to insert item to database with stars?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to record an item to database. However, i want sql convert it to stars so when i look records, i will not be able to understand what is written.

How can I do this ?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: İ am using mysql

Comment: Are you looking for a method to encrypt your data ? if so you need to use any hashing algorithm like `MD5`,`SHA1`

Comment: Yes iam @MJoy. And when i fetch that data, i want mysql convert to original version of data.  So  i should use what u recommended ?

Comment: @hakan Assuming your mid-ware is `PHP`, this would [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059151/encrypting-decrypting-passwords-to-and-from-a-mysql-database?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: İ m using c# @MJoy  did u see example about c#

Comment: Adding relevant tags to your questions would attract right audience

Comment: is there a way  if someone record an item to database, it converts to md5 on webservice, and save to database. when i see that md5 code, i could change to real text. However what i want is that, even i can not change it. How it is possible ?   @MJoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197138/discussion-between-mjoy-and-hakan).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best you could do would be to either maintain a separate column with the masked version of the data, or just generate the masked version when you query, e.g.

```
SELECT
    item,
    CONCAT(REPEAT('*', LENGTH(item)-4), RIGHT(item, 4)) AS item_masked
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to encrypt data that is written, so you need to also think how can you read this data or compare it. There are two options:

1. If you need just to compare data against what was entered, you can use hash functions, i.e. one-way encrypting. So once you hash it, you won't be able to decrypt it, you will just collect some other input, hash it and compare the outcome with what is in database.
2. Use some well known encrypting system, such as RSA, and store encrypted data in database. Then when you want to fetch it, just decrypt it using your private key.